# Can we predict the order of the results of a Hive SELECT * query?

Tags: hive, metastore, hive-metastore

Is it possible that the order of the results of a `SELECT * query (no ORDER BY)` is always the same provided that the same DBMS is used as Metastore?

So, as long as MySQL is used as Metastore, the order of the results for a `SELECT *;` query will always be the same. If Postgres is used, the order will be always the same on the same data, but different from when MySQL is used. I am talking about the same data.

Maybe it all boils down to the question of what is the default order of results and why is it different for MySQL and Postgres Metastore.

Comment: tables are inherently *unordered*. it doesn't change even if you use a DBMS as a metastore. Predictable ordering can only be expected when using an `order by`.

Comment: Still, when you perform a SELECT * FROM table; statement, without an order by clause, the results will come in some order. Question is whether it can be assumed, that the order will be the same after executing the same simple query several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as default order of rows, without `ORDER BY` the order is not guaranteed. This fact is not connected with Metastore database used.

In general data is being read in parallel by many processes (mappers), after splits were calculated, each process starts reading some piece of file or few files, depending on splits calculated. All parallel processes can process different volume of data and running on different nodes, the load is not the same each time, so they start returning rows and finishing at different times, depending on too many factors, such as node load, network load, volume of data per process, etc, etc. Removing all this factors you can increase the order prediction accuracy. Say, single thread sequential file read will return rows in the same order as they are in the file. But this is not how the database works.

Also according to Codd's relational theory, the order of columns and rows is immaterial to the database.

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand correctly, however, that a very simple query can be optimized into a single fetch task by Hive, and no MapReduce job will actually be started? So in this case it is just an interaction with HDFS directly. No mappers and reducers involved. Do you think it is okay to assume that the ordering will be the same, every time, I execute my query?

Comment: @Aron It may be for small table and simple query,  not sure maybe fetch task is also multi threaded , and what if your table have many files? you can do something to guarantee this behavior, ORDER BY - is the safe, right and efficient way.

Comment: Yes. Actually I am just wondering why a test case has been working for the last couple of hundred executions. The test case actually assumes order without any ORDER BY, and assumes a different order when HMS is Postgres and when it is MySQL... The table is very small, just 4 partitions, and one row in each partition... It is just some sanity check test case.

Comment: @Aron  Any correlation of row order in this case with metastore database is accidental and may change in in new software versions. Like it was in Oracle 8, when you did group by it also ordered by the same columns. This behavior has changed in next versions because group by was optimized and does not use ordering any more

Comment: thanks for your answers. I also think it has probably just been coincidence that the test case has worked so far, and it should probably be corrected to either not take into consideration the order of rows in the resultset or to use explicit ordering. It is just strange that the author of the test case had this apparently correct observation that the result rows came in one order when Postgres was used as Metastore and in another when MySQL was used as Metastore. As I said, the test case has run hundred's of times on both configurations.