# How can I preserve HIVE table order in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

There is a HIVE table where the rows have been saved in a certain order (time-based). However, the timestamp of each row has not been saved.

I want to read this table through PySpark and I want to preserve the order of the rows as they are in HIVE. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How are you getting the data for timestamp? BTW, You can directly read the table in the `DataFrame`  using `HiveContext()` along with sql() option. And, when you read this way, the **SCHEMA** is automatically inferred.

Comment: tables are inherently *unordered*. If there is a column that helps identify ordering use it in `order by` to get the desired ordering.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537971/2700344

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40264715/2700344

Comment: The last one actual helped. Thank you.